# How to create pivot table in sql Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table (Table_Marks) it contains value as described below: -

```
CLASS | STD | NAME   | SUBJECT | PT1_M | PTB1_M | PT2_M | PTB2_M | 
1     | ST1 | NITYA  | ENG     | 12    | 15     | 30    | 9      |
1     | ST1 | NITYA  | HIN     | 2     | 22     | 25    | 6      |
1     | ST1 | NITYA  | MATH    | 3     | 10     | 32    | 8      |
1     | ST2 | SHIV   | ENG     | AB    | AB     | 10    | 2      |
1     | ST2 | SHIV   | HIN     | 2     | 22     | 20    | 1      |
1     | ST2 | SHIV   | MATH    | 3     | 10     | AB    | 5      |
```

Now I want to use this as PIVOT TABLE as described below: -

```
CLASS|STD |NAME  |ENG     |HIN    |MATH   |T1 |ENG    |HIN    |MATH   |T2  |T1+T2|
                 |PT1|PB1 |PT1|PB1|PT1|PB1|   |PT2|PB2|PT2|PB2|PT2|PB2|     
1    |STD1|NITYA |12 |15  |2  |22 |3  |10 |64 |30 |9  |25 |6  |32 |8  |110 |174
1    |STD2|SHIV  |AB |AB  |2  |22 |3  |10 |37 |10 |2  |20 |1  |AB |5  |38  |75
```

Please help any one

Comment: [mcve] Show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

```
|ENG     |HIN    |MATH   |T1 |ENG    |HIN    |MATH   |T2  |T1+T2|
                 |PT1|PB1 |PT1|PB1|PT1|PB1|   |PT2|PB2|PT2|PB2|PT2|PB2|
```

Above mentioned columns are called super columns /Super column family in Cassandra . If I am not wrong super column doesn't exist in SQL Server 2008 or  in most of the relational databases.

Comment: |E_PT1|E_PB1 |H_PT1|H_PB1|M_PT1|M_PB1|   |E_PT2|E_PB2|H_PT2|H_PB2|M_PT2|M_PB2|

Comment: in the end t1+t2

Answer (score 0):

Change the alias name as per your need :

```
create TABLE student_marks 
(
  CLASS int,
  standard varchar(100),
  name char(20),
  SUBJECT char(20),
  PT1_M int,
  PTB1_M int,
  PT2_M int,
  PTB2_M int 
  );
  insert into student_marks values (1,'ST1','NITYA','ENG', 12,15,30,9);
  insert into student_marks values (1,'ST1','NITYA','HIN', 16,18,31,8) ;
```

Solution :

```
SELECT
CLASS,
STANDARD,
NAME,
SUBJECT,
PT1,
PB1,
(PT1+PB1) AS  T1,
PT2,
PB2,
(PT2+PB2) AS  T2,
(PT1+PB1+PT2+PB2) AS T1T2
FROM(

SELECT
CLASS,
STANDARD,
NAME,
SUBJECT,
CASE WHEN SUBJECT in ('ENG','HIN') THEN PT1_M ELSE 0 END AS PT1,
CASE WHEN SUBJECT in ('ENG','HIN') THEN PTB1_M  ELSE 0 END AS PB1,
CASE WHEN SUBJECT in ('ENG','HIN') THEN PT2_M ELSE 0 END AS PT2,
CASE WHEN SUBJECT in ('ENG','HIN') THEN  PTB2_M  ELSE 0 END AS PB2
FROM STUDENT_MARKS
)
C
```